# Puedo poner una variable tipo string en mi cadena de conexión Sql Server?

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

```
 Public Property NomBdGeneral() As String

    Get
        Return VnumEmp
    End Get
    Set
        VnumEmp = Value
    End Set
End Property
Public VnumEmp As String

Public CadConex As String = "Data Source=WIN-59UIUI1KGPN\SAMIT; Initial Catalog=" & VnumEmp & ";user id = sa; password = 2121121512"
```

La he intentado así y con los plus pero no asigna el valor para Initial Catalog que en este caso es el nombre de la base de datos.
Gracias..

Comment: en que contencto defines el codigo que estas mostrando? esta dentro de alguna clase, puedes validar que hayas asignado valor a la propiedad

Comment: Amigo Tuttini lo tengo en un modulo y lo que hago es que mediante otra conexión le envío el string con el nombre de la base de datos y se carga normal pero no se asigna al momento de usarla, de qui le envío la variable `nomBdGeneral = numEmp + "GENERAL"`
                `mdlGeneral.NomBdGeneral = nomBdGeneral`

Comment: no uses modulos, usa clases, programa orientado a objetos. Si quieres despues la instancia de la clase mantenla como variable global en el modulo

Answer (score 1):

Podrias intentar definiendo algo como esto

```
Public Class Class1

    Private VnumEmp As String
    Public Property NomBdGeneral() As String
        Get
            Return VnumEmp
        End Get
        Set
            VnumEmp = Value
        End Set
    End Property


    Public  ReadOnly Property CadConex() As String
        Get
            Return String.Format("Data Source=WIN-59UIUI1KGPN\SAMIT; Initial Catalog={0};user id = sa; password = 2121121512", Me.NomBdGeneral)
        End Get
    End Property

End Class
```

Y lo usarias de esta forma

```
Dim cls As New Class1

cls.NomBdGeneral = "nombredb"

Dim connstring As String = cls.CadConex
```

la idea es instanciar la clase, asignar la propiedad NomBdGeneral y luego obtener la conexion

Comment: Sabes que si asigna la variable pero cuando la voy a utilizar aqui Initial Catalog llega vacio.

Comment: Muchos carateres, la cuestion es que es un metodo para llenar un cbx, y uso la cadena de conexion cadConex y en ese momento no tiene el valor que se le asigno

Comment: eso pude ser porque el connection string lo armas dinamico en una variable publica, intenta definirlo en una propiedad readonly como puse en el ejemplo

Answer (score 0):

Debia declararla de la siguiente manera

```
Public Shared Property NomBdGeneral() As String

    Get
        Return VnumEmp
    End Get
    Set
        VnumEmp = Value
    End Set
End Property
Private Shared VnumEmp As String
```

Pero no en un module si no en una clase.

Comment: claro eso es lo que decia debes usar clases no modulo, pero ojo porque las clases debes instanciarlas

Answer (score 0):

¿Ya viste si la libreria "ConfigurationManager" esta habilitada? A mi me pasaba eso cuando quería llamar un string para conectar.